# how to remove emulator from tool window android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

for the new android version 4.1 or newer, we can run the emulator directly to the android studio tool window. it's good. so I add an emulator there, but I face some problems seeing this full screen of the emulator if I open logcat. so, now I want to remove the emulator from there. (i am unable to find out this setting, that where we remove this connection form directly show in android studio).

see this image,(it helps you to get my question proper)

again, in short, I want to remove the emulator tool window from my android studio. (i want to directly open this in the default way)

[image]

Answer (score 128, accepted):

go to File -> Setting -> tools -> Emulator and uncheck the checkbox (Launch in tool window) and apply changes. That's it. and restart your emulator

Comment: I've already checked this option to open the emulator in tool window, but Emulator again opens in standalone window. why?

Comment: Thanks very helpful.

Comment: Still works in Android Studio Bumblebee

Answer (score 41):

For Windows,

**Step 1 :**
**File -> Setting -> Tools -> Emulator**
Just **uncheck** the checkbox of **"Launch in tool window"** & click on Apply at right bottom & restart Emulator again.

For Mac OS,

**Step 1 :**
**Android Studio -> Preference -> Tools -> Emulator**
Just **uncheck** the checkbox of **"Launch in tool window"** & click on Apply at right bottom & restart Emulator again.

If still emulator is in Tool Window then first you need to stop running emulator in Tool Window.

For stop emulator,

**Step 2**
**Open AVD Manager -> Choose down arrow of your selected emulator -> click on "Stop"**.

Just verify **Step 1** before running your application again.
Now you have to run your application.

Comment: The second step, work for me, you have to first stop the emulator to this change take effect

Comment: Thank you for this. I don't know how anyone can use the new in-window system. It's impossible to see the device as the lower window opens.

Comment: I had to relaunch the Android Studio but it worked on Windows running Chipmunk edition, thanks

Answer (score 10):

Step 1 : Android Studio -> Preference -> Tools -> Emulator Just uncheck the checkbox of "Launch in tool window" & click on Apply at right bottom & delete your emulator & create a new emulator

Comment: ı was have your problem and ı fix it

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what half of the other answers are already saying, including [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65403817/how-to-remove-emulator-from-tool-window-android-studio/65404059#65404059)

Comment: This is the correct answer in October 2022

Answer (score 2):

Go to Android Studio ->Preference->emulator->deselect `Launch in a toolbar window`
After applying change do invalidate and restart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You only need to click on the `x` of your emulator window.

[Emulator tool window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwKNT.png)

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what half of the other answers are already saying, including [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65404059/14267427).

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a way to undock the emulator without changing the default setting (because I like it docked, most of the time)... right click on the emulators tab and see:
[image]