# Is there away to switch back to the standalone emulator in Android Studio/Intellij Idea?

Tags: android, android-emulator

**Problem:** I cannot find a way to switch the emulator for testing an Android app back to a standalone?

I've been using the standalone versions of emulator devices for a year or so. I switched to the internal emulator and have nothing but problems, very unstable. I haven't been able to find how to switch back to standalone.

**What I have done"** I've tried searching this forum and elsewhere but didn't really find anything pertaining to switching back, only how to make them work internally to the IDE. I'm sure I may be missing something simple, I just haven't found it.

Comment: @Morrison Chang - Standalone is not my term, its not unfamiliar to me. A standalone, as I understand it, can be launched and controlled by the IDE but if I close the IDE it can still operate independently as a separate device -- standalone. An embedded one closes when you close the IDE. They visually look subtly different... you can see a couple picks here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983351/taking-screenshot-on-emulator-from-android-studio

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it also isn't an different product.

Comment: @Morrison Chang - Perfect! That worked. I appreciate your help and patience with it. All issues with the devices I created went away. If you want to post your comment as an answer I can mark it for you. Thanks again!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65403817/how-to-remove-emulator-from-tool-window-android-studio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you describe seems like Android Studio IDE Emulator Tool Window feature:

[image: Android Studio Emulator Tool Window]

Which is documented at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#run-emulator-studio

You should be able to disable/toggle the feature in Android Studio IDE menus from Preferences/Settings -> Tool menu -> Emulator panel.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. On Intellij 2022.2.1 I get this checkbox in Tools > Android Emulator > Launch in a tool window. https://i.imgur.com/yLSY9Wq.png